# Only show 'x' amount of latest results JSON + jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have this work thats work great.

```
(function() {

    // What JSON do you want to get? Note: If you're making a request from your own domain to your own domain, delete &callback=?.
    var url = 'http://myurl/guest-posts/?category=ffm&format=json&callback=?';

    $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) { // Adds the JSON to the data variable.

        // Create the HTML string.
        var headerContent = '<h1><a href="' + data.website.authenticUrl + '">' + data.website.siteTitle + '</a></h1>';

        // Set the HTML.
        $('#header').html(headerContent);

        $(data.items).each(function() {
            var post =  '<a href="http://myurl/' + this.fullUrl + '"><h2>' + this.title + '</h2></a><img src= "'+this.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+this.filename+'"><a href="http://myurl/' + this.fullUrl + '">Read More</a>' ;
            $('#blog').append(post);
        });
    });
})();
```

I want it to show the 6 latest posts. I dont know how to loop it so that only the 6 newest posts will be showing. Overriding the older posts if you want to call it that.

ATM i have 3 posts assigned to the cateogry which show in the correct order. title, image thumbnail and then a read more link whcih goes to the post.

I just to loop it all so at any given time there is only 6 articles, being the most recent one first.

Quick image of it working.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide an higher resolution screenshot of your code?

Comment: Or even better, link to the codepen example.

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't your own website that is supplying the JSON? If not, then you may well need to do the limiting on the client side in jQuery. It is worth checking before you do this if you can limit them via. the query string itself and let the source of the JSON limit the results to reduce overhead. Also, it would be worth storing the results of the query instead of requesting the JSON every time the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly check for the index in .each() loop and break the loop after 6 times, like:

```
$(data.items).each(function(index) {
if(index>5)
 return false;
else{
      var post =  '<a href="my-url/' + this.fullUrl + '"><h2>'     + this.title + '</h2></a><img src= "'+this.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+this.filename+'"><a href="my-url/' + this.fullUrl + '">Read More</a>' ;
      $('#blog').append(post);
      return true;
    }
    });
```

This will break loop after 6 iterations!

Comment: it might worth me adding more then 6 posts so we can see if this is working as there is only 3 at the moment.

Comment: if you find any answer helpful, don't forget to upvote it. I think, this is the best way to appreciate any answer here!

Comment: just says i need to level 15 :( which sucks but i gave it a tick.

Comment: now that i have a set amount of posts, how would i go about using it a slider for instance, using something like nivo slider for example that feeds its images in <li>. Would be great to get these links auto updating inside a slider. thanks.

Comment: Here is a link for creating nio slider : http://www.templatemonster.com/help/jquery-nivoslider.html. In your case, you can initialize your slider after .each() function.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as

```
 $(data.items).each(function(index) {
    //Stop 
    if(index > 5)
         return; 

   var post =  '<a href="my-url/' + this.fullUrl + '"><h2>' + this.title + '</h2></a><img src= "'+this.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+this.filename+'"><a href="my-url.com/' + this.fullUrl + '">Read More</a>' ;
      $('#blog').append(post);
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B8kQ9/

Comment: thanks very much for the quick response, ill responde when finished thanks

Comment: This will show 7 items since `index` is 0-based. The condition should be `index > 5`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(data.items).each(function() {
        var post =  '<a href="http://fantasyfootballpundits.com/' + this.fullUrl + '"><h2>' + this.title + '</h2></a><img src= "'+this.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+this.filename+'"><a href="http://fantasyfootballpundits.com/' + this.fullUrl + '">Read More</a>' ;
        $('#blog').append(post);
    });
```

^^ that code loops through each item in data, so it's not limiting it to only 6

you can use something like this to loop using a normal for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if(data.items[i] != null)
    {
        var current = data.items[i];
        var post =  '<a href="http://fantasyfootballpundits.com/' + current.fullUrl + '"><h2>'     + current.title + '</h2></a><img src= "'+current.assetUrl+'" alt ="'+current.filename+'"><a href="http://fantasyfootballpundits.com/' + current.fullUrl + '">Read More</a>' ;
        $('#blog').append(post);
    }
}
```

hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: ill gave a go with this now mate. Cheers, ill post any problems after. Thanks

Comment: This works like a gem. along with what @SanjeevRai also put down.